# MediaWiki setOption() on own PHP page

Tags: php, mysql, mediawiki

i have a problem :) I want to use an own PHP file on my server which has the ability to change Options of Users registered in the MediaWiki Installation on same server. For this i have load the webstart and autoload includes. Now, i can read settings of the user logged in at this time without problems. But, if i want to save the edited setting (with setOption()), it appears the following notice:

> Notice: Uncommitted DB writes (transaction from DatabaseBase::query (LCStoreDB::get)). in /var/www/wiki/includes/db/Database.php on line 4065 Notice: DB transaction callbacks still pending (from Title::invalidateCache). in /var/www/wiki/includes/db/Database.php on line 4073

and the Option isn't saved to the database :( Have anyone an idea, how to do my task, or how i can solve my problem?

Thanks!

Here is the code:

```
<?php
$IP = strval( getenv( 'MW_INSTALL_PATH' ) ) !== ''
    ? getenv( 'MW_INSTALL_PATH' )
    : realpath( __DIR__ . '/' );
require_once "$IP/includes/AutoLoader.php";
require_once( "$IP/includes/WebStart.php" );

$t = new User();
$user = $t->newFromSession();
if(!isset($wgCommandLineMode) && !isset($_COOKIE[session_name()])) {
    wfSetupSession();
}
if ($user->isLoggedIn()) {
    $user->setOption( 'skinname', 'vector' );
    $user->setCookies();
    $user->saveSettings();
}
```

?>

Comment: Possibly related to [this known bug](https://bugzilla.wikimedia.org/show_bug.cgi?id=56269)?

Comment: Thanks for that, maybe it's the same bug, i have posted there and will test after a bugfix for that, thx :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to properly shut down the database connection when using automatic transactions (which is the default when $wgCommandLineMode is true). Add something like this at the end of your file:

```
$lb = wfGetLBFactory();
$lb->shutdown();
```

You'd also probably want to catch any exceptions that might be thrown and do a rollback on all open database connections. As for [MediaWiki bug 56269](https://bugzilla.wikimedia.org/show_bug.cgi?id=56269%20MediaWiki%20bug%2056269), that's not your issue (although the lack of an ability to do a rollback on all open database connections is probably contributing to that bug).

Comment: Thanks, that's it :) In my code i have a try catch construct, so, if any error occur, the script rollback the changes :) Big thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try subclassing the Maintenance class in includes/Maintenance.php and implement the abstract execute function with the desired code.  I encountered the same warnings/no saves as you did with uncommitted transactions.  Following the example in createAndPromote.php, the database transactions were committed.

Comment: Tried, but the same error :/ I have tried also this http://forge.typo3.org/issues/54257 but does not work, too. I think, i will wait, until the bug liked from Patrick Q is fixed, thx nevertheless.